# Simple Java regex

Tags: java, regex

Finding Java tedious after Python. Looking to parse some base64 concated data.

How do I split a simple string on one or more equals '='?

What is wrong with this simple regex? (it's Java codebase under the Jython hood)

```
>>> s = "hello=world"
>>> s.split("=+")
['hello=world']
>>> s.split("=*")
['hello=world']
>>> s.split("=")
['hello', 'world']
```

Comment: That is not possible that way you want. With a regex you have only **one** pattern. And that patter has to match. No matter if you use *, + or what ever.

Comment: what???????????????????????? supply a beginning string and what stuff you want parsed out of it so we can help.

Comment: Not sure why you get these results but `split("=+")` works fine in pure Java.

Comment: @progenhard I thought it was very clear. `s = "hello=world"` `regex = "=+"`. Did you read the question b4 marking down?

Comment: @Pshemo Just for my skills. How should the String look like if you split it by "=+". What where is he spliting?

Comment: @Gerret in regex `+` means one or more continuous occurrences of previously described string, so `=+` mean on one or more continues equation marks like `=` `==` `===` (you get the idea). So for data like `Hello=beautiful==day` iy will split into `["hello", "beautiful", "day"]`

Comment: @drew I am not sure if that is correct answer because it doesn't tell why you have your problem :/ Maybe as James Anderson pointed in his answer `Jython` doesn't use regex in his `split` method. This would have sense because your string doesn't contain `=+` or `=*` substrings so it cant split on them, but on single `=` it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem!

Your code is valid Java syntax for splitting.

BUT

You are using Jython and Jython `string.split()` splits on character string not a regex.

You need to use the Jython `re.split` to break up the string.

Comment: Sweet I'll stick to pure Java I guess. Jython is so nice for complex Java testing though :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this?

```
  ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)=*([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/wKNBgwaN9s4FF3p2)

Comment: No. Did you read the question?? `How do I split a simple string on one or more equals '='?` It will be Base64 encoding concatenated, thus providing 1..* '=' characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just an issue with Jython. FYI

Input

```
        decryptKeySplits("Testing=hello");
        decryptKeySplits("Testing====hello");
        decryptKeySplits("Testing=hello==");
        decryptKeySplits("Testing=hello=this=it");
```

Results

```
2
2
2
4
```